# Probability question involving colored dice

Tags: probability, dice

This question is really getting to me, a friend of mine has suggested a solution but I believe it is incorrect.
Anyway here's the question:

> You throw 9 coloured dice. Every dice has 2 white sides, 2 red sides and 2 blue sides. What is the chance to get every color three times?

I'd be over the moon if you can help me find the solution as it's been getting to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since each colour is on two sides, the probability for each colour on each die is $1/3$. (Unfortunately we can't say that the dice are equivalent to $3$-sided dice because there's no such thing.)

The probability to get every colour thrice is the number of ways of colouring nine dice with three dice coloured in each colour, over the number of ways of colouring nine dice with three colours. The latter is simply $3^9$, and the former is the multinomial coefficient

$$
\left({9\atop3,3,3}\right)=\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}=1680\;,
$$

so the probability is

$$
\frac{1680}{3^9}=\frac{560}{3^8}=\frac{560}{6561}\approx0.085\;.
$$

Comment: You could always throw a [Toblerone bar](http://www.statisticool.com/3sided.htm) to get a three-sided die effect.

Comment: @TMM: :-) True -- except you either have to throw it such that it can't land on its end, or stipulate that you throw again in the unlikely event that it does -- or I guess you could round off the ends in a symmetric way such that it can't stand on them.

Comment: Apparently some people have already [made 3-sided dice](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:04ds3.JPG), even without rounding off the ends. So your claim in the second line is wrong! You're lucky that I upvoted your answer before checking whether all your claims were correct :P

Comment: @TMM: The caption claims that these are $3$-sided dice, but they're in fact $5$-sided dice with different probabilities for the two groups of $3$ and $2$ equivalent sides. One would have to make some effort at making the probability for the $2$ sides zero, either by rounding them off or by rethrowing them or perhaps by some other means, in order to justify calling them "$3$-sided dice".

Comment: Still, you claimed that "there's no such thing [as $3$-sided dice]", while I showed you that they *do* exist. You may argue that they are actually $5$-sided, but they are classified as $3$-sided on for instance the [Portuguese Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometria_dos_dados). And Wikipedia is always right ;-)

Comment: @TMM: I never argued against that. My first response to your first comment was "True".

Answer (score 0):

The probability we get exactly $3$ white is, by the standard "binomial distribution" formula, equal to 
$$\binom{9}{3}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^6.$$
**Given** that we got exactly $3$ blue, the number of red is equal to $3$ with probability
$$\binom{6}{3}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^3.$$
Multiply. There is some simplification, since the $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^6$ in the second expression cancels the $2$'s in the first. And the product 
$\binom{9}{6}\binom{6}{3}$ "simplifies" to $\dfrac{9!}{(3!)^3}$.

Comment: AH thank you! this is roughly what I did.